# Subversion intermittent hanging on commit problem

Tags: svn

I have a program which makes changes to a relatively small Excel file, then commits it to a Subversion repository.

Every so often, subversion will hang indefinitely while attempting to commit.  But if I close the program and re-run it (so it commits again), it works fine.

I am using TortoiseSVN 1.6.10, and I'm not honestly sure how to check what version of SVN is running on the server.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Whet method are you using to connect (`ssh+svn`, `file:///`, `https` etc.), and is there anything in those respective logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running a scheduled task with the command: `"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe" /command:cleanup /path:"PATHHERE" /closeonend:1`
seems to do the trick, but I still can't help but wonder if there's a better solution.